# py.test skip depending on parameters

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I want exhaustively test function by calling it with all possible argument combinations:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1, 2])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("b", [1, 2, 3, 4])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("c", [1, 2, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("d", [1, 2])
def test_func_variations(a, b, c, d):
    assert func(a, b, c, d) == a*b*c+d
```

Though some of these combinations don't make sense. Is there an easy way to skip these combinations with py.test, e.g. too have logic like this:

```
def test_func_variations(a, b, c, d):
    if (a == 1 and b in (2, 3)) or (a == 2 and c == 3):
        skip_me()
    assert func(a, b, c, d) == a*b*c+d
```

Comment: [*"Alternatively, it is also possible to skip imperatively during test execution or setup by calling the `pytest.skip(reason)` function..."*](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html)

Comment: I mean you can literally have the logic you show in your question, but replace `skip_me` with `pytest.skip`.

Comment: You right @jonrsharpe, somehow missed that, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Okay, that was easy:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", [1, 2])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("b", [1, 2, 3, 4])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("c", [1, 2, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("d", [1, 2])
def test_func_variations(a, b, c, d):
    if (a == 1 and b in (2, 3)) or (a == 2 and c == 3):
        pytest.skip("invalid parameter combination")
    assert func(a, b, c, d) == a*b*c+d
```

Answer (score 0):

Although running an 'if' condition inside the test is valid, a more correct solution would be to indicate the "combinations" expected to fail on XFail. See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions/8304

However, this is currently not supported by pytest.

Comment: Thanks for offering additional information.  However, this is not actually an answer to the question.  (And... this question already has an answer which appears to be valid.)  Soon, when you get a reputation of 50, you will be able to post comments; that would be a good way to share thoughts like this.